# Hide specific image which have same class of other using only CSS

Tags: css

I have a page who contain 2 icons and I need to hide one of them. The problem is both image have the same class so I can't simply use `.color_box {display:none;}` because in this case, both image will be hidden. The only difference between these 2 images are their own title tag, so I wondering if is possible to do something with this. Here an example of code:

```
<img title="Annotation" class="color_box" src="http://www.site.com/images1.png">

<img title="Reservation" class="color_box" src="http://www.site.com/images2.png">
```

Precision:

- I don't have access to html of the related page
- I'm allowed to use only CSS by modifying a global stylesheet file
- The use of Javascript is not possible

Any suggestion ?

Comment: `img[title="Annotation"] { display: none; }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors). They work all the way back to IE7.

```
img[title="Annotation"], img[src$="images2.png"] { display: none }
```

As @Jon noted, this is completely dependent upon the HTML, so if it changes, you're kind of screwed. I included the `src` attribute just to illustrate that it's a possibility as well.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an [attribute value selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors) to target just one image:

```
img[title=Annotation] { display: none; }
```

This is prone to breaking if the HTML changes without warning, but given the restrictions you have given there's no better option.